# Clone works for all clicked elements instead of this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clone img of .selectedIcon into clicked .icon > then if clicked another .icon I need to edit only the selected .icon. My solution edits all clicked .icon. Is there any alternative to .click() that would solve this?

```js
$(".icon").on("click", function() {
  let thisIcon = $(this);
  alert("icon clicked");
  $(".icons").fadeIn("slow");

  function imagePicker() {
    $(".iconSelect").on("click", function() {
      $(".selectedIcon").html("");
      $(this).clone().appendTo(".selectedIcon");
      $(thisIcon).html("");
      $(".selectedIcon img").clone().appendTo(thisIcon);
    })
  }
  imagePicker();
})
```

```css
.icons {
  display: none;
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panels">
  <div class="first hidden">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="icon 20iconA">A</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="icon 20iconB">B</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!--image picker -->
<div class="iconEditWrap">
  <div class="iconEdit">
    <div class="selectedIcon">
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      <img class="iconSelect" alt="img1">
      <img class="iconSelect" alt="img2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think every time you click `.icon`, a new click handler is added to `".iconSelect"` which is wrong

Comment: Then should i rewrite it to focus() ? that wont work either i think

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle to make it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish? You have your function inside the click which will add the next click event also on your old selection.

```js
let thisIcon;
$(".icon").on("click", function() {
  thisIcon = $(this);
  alert("icon clicked");
  $(".icons").fadeIn("slow");

  
  //imagePicker();
})

//function imagePicker() {
    $(".iconSelect").on("click", function() {
      $(".selectedIcon").html("");
      $(this).clone().appendTo(".selectedIcon");
      $(thisIcon).html("");
      $(".selectedIcon img").clone().appendTo(thisIcon);
    })
  //}
```

```css
.icons {
  display: none;
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panels">
  <div class="first hidden">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="icon 20iconA">A</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="icon 20iconB">B</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!--image picker -->
<div class="iconEditWrap">
  <div class="iconEdit">
    <div class="selectedIcon">
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      <img class="iconSelect" alt="img1">
      <img class="iconSelect" alt="img2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here also a new click event handler will be added to `iconSelect`, every time you click `.icon`. Try a `console.log` to see the number of times `iconSelect`'s handler is getting called

Comment: @CerlinBoss thank you for pointing this out, I completely overlooked it. I adjusted it without the imagePicker function so now it only gets called when it is actually clicked.